# I have set Family link for 1:30 hour but my child watches movies all day long

Tags: android

I set up family link for my child on a Samsung A53 with latest updates.

I have set the timer for 1:30h per day and gave infinite time for WhatsApp, messages and a few google apps like Chrome, S Suggest, Calendar, Camera, clock, Contacts, Gmail, google, google drive, google meet.
YouTube and YouTube music are set for 1h.

When my child swipes right he has a list of movies... from YouTube. Some of them won't work with the message time's up you reached your daily limit, ask your parent if you need more time. But other movies are playing as you can see in the attached screen capture video.

I think the time is adding up to "google chrome" as i can see that my child has spent a lot of time on it in "time spent" option from family link on my phone. Yet, this is an incorrect behavior of family link / YouTube / chrome option!

Please visualize the file attached or the link here: [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/aDo7y_9YEWs)

I hope someone will understand the problem and address it.

Thanx
Marius Socaciu

`image01`[image01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYnIy.png)
`image02`[image02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FznFD.png)
`image03`[image03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/432jd.png)
`image04`[image04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M65eQ.png)

Tried to set limits for all google apps but he still have acces to the movies...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think this question is better suited for [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) after some formatting fixes.